# how to convert a datetime.time() object to datetime.datetime object pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame([{'st':datetime.datetime.strptime('21:00:00','%H:%M:%S').time(),'et':datetime.datetime.strptime('22:00:00','%H:%M:%S').time()}, {'st':datetime.datetime.strptime('1:00:00','%H:%M:%S').time(),'et':datetime.datetime.strptime('3:00:00','%H:%M:%S').time()}])


Out[183]: df
         et        st
0  22:00:00  21:00:00
1  03:00:00  01:00:00
```

I would like to be able to convert the above dataframe with new fields having `datetime.datetime` objects with two other extra columns such as here having any dummy date in it and using the time from their respective rows:

```
      et        st      sdate_time                edate_time
0  22:00:00  21:00:00   2018-01-01 21:00:00      2018-01-01 22:00:00  
1  03:00:00  01:00:00   2018-01-01 1:00:00       2018-01-01 3:00:00
```

The approach I have tried is using apply method

```
df['et'].apply(lambda et: pd.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date(),et))
```

but turns out that the dataframe could be really huge and I would like to vectorize the above operation without the apply method .

Comment: Does `df.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H:%M:%S')` work for you?  Where the date is 1900-01-01?

Comment: apply() should not be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
date = str(datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date())

df['edate_time'] = pd.to_datetime(date + " " + df.et.astype(str))

       et          st            edate_time
0   22:00:00    21:00:00    2018-01-01 22:00:00
1   03:00:00    01:00:00    2018-01-01 03:00:00
```

Comment: This anwer relies on a "fake" date

Comment: @Tobbey What do you mean by a "fake date" ?

Comment: An arbitrary date '2018-01-01' with an arbitrary format needs to be provided.

Comment: @Tobbey Do you have a better idea for an object, which *only* holds time information? You need to define a fixed data.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df.assign(sdate_time=pd.to_datetime(df['et'], format='%H:%M:%S'), 
          edate_time=pd.to_datetime(df['st'], format='%H:%M:%S'))
```

Output:

```
         et        st          sdate_time          edate_time
0  22:00:00  21:00:00 1900-01-01 22:00:00 1900-01-01 21:00:00
1  03:00:00  01:00:00 1900-01-01 03:00:00 1900-01-01 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there no better way of doing this than to assign a random date?

I have matplotlib version '3.3.1' and still face this issue of not being able to plot a datetime.time object for which I do not need a date but only the 24 hours of a day.

I've seen workarounds for the label, using `import matplotlib.dates as mdates` but still not the best way.