# Seaborn regression plot with datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to produce a Regression/Scatterplot with a `datetime.time` object between the Amplitude of several Nerves and the Time they have been in use in a trial.

```
>>> df.head()
   Amp strain 8 min [mA] Time in use [hh:mm]
0                    0.1            00:22:00
1                    0.0            00:46:00
2                    0.8            00:18:00
3                    0.3            00:23:00
4                    0.6            00:14:00
```

However `sns.regplot(y=df.iloc[:, 1], x=df.iloc[:, 0])` causes a

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'
```

I tried everything from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54702185/matplotlib-seaborn-scatter-plot-with-datetime-object-on-x-axis-and-days-with-mul) to [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52955534/how-to-convert-a-datetime-time-object-to-datetime-datetime-object-pandas) and several other links that I can't find anymore but haven't been able to do so. Is there anything I haven't seen yet?

Comment: try `sns.regplot(y=df.iloc[:, 0], x=df.iloc[:, 1])`

Comment: Although that creates an empty figure, the error remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by

1. [converting the datetime object to string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694025/converting-a-datetime-column-back-to-a-string-columns-pandas-python)
2. [replacing the colons](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace)
3. [converting the series to a numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677933/converting-object-to-int-pandas)

Code:

```
df["Time in use [hh:mm]"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Time in use [hh:mm]"].astype(str).str.replace(":", ""))
sns.regplot(y=df["Time in use [hh:mm]"], x=df["Amp strain 8 min [mA]"])
```

This produces a `SettingWithCopyWarning` that [can be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas), but I'm not sure if that's advisable.